# UIScrollView start zooming when rotate view Swift, how disable zooming?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

UIScrollView start zooming when rotate view Swift, how disable zooming?

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, 
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: IGestureRecognizer
)->Bool{ return true }
```

Answer (score 0):

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize,
  with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { [weak self] _ in
    if let scrollView = self?.scrollView {
        self?.scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView)
    }
  }, completion: nil)

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To Disable Zooming of the scrollview we can use these :-

```
1) yourscrollview.minimumZoomScale=yourscrollview.maximumZoomScale
```

2) For Pinch or Pan Gesture :-

```
    yourscrollview.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
    yourscrollview.panGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
```

3) Using Set scale

```
    yourscrollview.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    yourscrollview.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    yourscrollview.bounces = false
    yourscrollview.bouncesZoom = false
```